# Is there a way to import fields from a Microsoft Form into a SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, form, flow

I have a Microsoft Form with ~20 questions on it and would like to store the User's input from this form to a SharePoint list via Flow.

Is there an easy way to import columns from the Form, or do I need to manually create each of the columns?

Comment: What kind of "Form" is it?

Comment: Microsoft Form (Updated original to clarify)

Comment: Is it possible to import information from database to the form? like a dropdown that has information from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Microsoft Forms:

- Create a single response (in order to download the response Excel Sheet).
- Download the Response (Responses tab then choose Open in Excel)
- In the ... menu on the Responses tab choose **Delete all responses** to clear out your dummy response

Then on your SharePoint site (from IE):

- Go to Site Contents
- Choose New > App
- Choose Import Spreadsheet
- Give your list a name and choose the response excel file downloaded earlier
- Click Import

Flow:

- There's a template called **Record form responses in SharePoint** where you can map your form to your new list and that should do it

Comment: Worked perfectly! Only question is why it doesn't tell you to switch to IE before the last SharePoint step?

Comment: Glad it worked for you! The Import from Spreadsheet is pretty old and relies on Active X. So Chrome won't work. The site also needs to be a trusted site (or you'll get an invalid spreadsheet or something error). Very user friendly!