# Update SharePoint Online list when new row is added to Excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, flow

So, I'm working on this project where my client wants to send forms with simple yes and no questions to their customers, adding each customer to a SharePoint list when the form is submitted. The customers gets different scores depending on their answers. My client is using Office 365 and wants it all "out of the box".

What I have done i I've created a form (with Forms) that adds a row with the answers and the score to a new row on an Excel spreadsheet every time one hits the submit button on the form. So far, so good. What i need help with is exporting and updating the spreadsheet to a SharePoint list. I have been looking at Flow and think that's the way to go, but I'm in over my head. Suggestions? Help? Tips?

Comment: You're almost there! See my answer here on how to do this with Flow: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/235476/2881